# Question Regarding Upper and Lower Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Suppose that $m, M ∈ \mathbb{R}$ with $m ≤ f(x) ≤ M$
for all $x ∈ [a, b]$. Explain why it is necessarily true that the upper integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and the lower integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ both exist as real numbers.  Why is it true that $m(b − a)$ ≤ $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ ≤ $M(b − a)$?

Attempted Solution: I think I have some idea on how to answer the first part. The reason being is that since $f$ is bounded, and because the lower and upper integrals are defined by supremum and infinum respectively, you are guaranteed that lower/upper integral to be real numbers.

As for the question why the Riemmann integral is between $m(b-a)$ and $M(b-a)$, I am not sure.

Note: I could not find the command for upper and lower integral so if someone could edit that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/%7Eplaval/math4382/funcintRDProp.pdf).

Then we get

$$\int_a^b m dx\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx\leq \int_a^b Mdx $$

and the result follows.